# edit json file with custom functions | discord.js, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

hey I have a file of a JSON data like this called `data.json`:

```
"servers":
{
   "sv-123344":
   {
      "owner": "id",
      "vstats": false
   },
   "sv-44332211":
   {
      "owner": "id",
      "vstats": false
   }
},

"users":
{
    "uid-111222":
    {
       "favlist":
       [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
       ]
    },

    "uid-445566":
    {
       "favlist":
       [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
       ]
    }
}
```

So Basicly i want 3 Functions that i dont know how to write them

**1-** i need a function to check that if an input is exist in `favlist` of a user or not
like this: `if(checkExist(userid, input) == true)`

**2-** i need a function to add the input to the `favlist`
like this: `addFav(userid, input)`

**3-** and i need a remove function to remove the input from the `favlist`
like: `removeFav(userid, input)`

so i would be so thankfull if anyone can help me with this codes
and all the credits will go to anyone who helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` Object is missing some `{}` also to be able to remove data from array/object you need you use array function like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
js={"servers":{ "sv-123344": { "owner": "id", "vstats": false }, "sv-44332211": { "owner": "id", "vstats": false } }, "users": { "uid-111222": { "favlist": [ "1", "2", "3" ] }, "uid-445566": { "favlist": [ "1", "2", "3" ] } } }


function checkfav(userid,input){
  var bool
  Object.entries(js.users).forEach(o=>{
    if(o[0]==userid){
      var inp=input.toString()
      bool= o[1].favlist.includes(inp)
    } 
  })
  return bool
}

function addtofav(userid,input){
  var ar
  Object.entries(js.users).forEach(o=>{
    inp=input.toString()
     if(o[0]==userid)
     o[1].favlist.push(inp)
     ar=o[1].favlist
  })
  return ar
}

function removeFav(userid, input){
  var arr
  Object.entries(js.users).forEach(o=>{
    inp=input.toString()
     if(o[0]==userid){
      if(o[1].favlist.includes(inp)){
        o[1].favlist.splice(o[1].favlist.indexOf(inp),1)
       }
       arr=o[1].favlist
    }
     })
     
  return arr
}

console.log(checkfav(1))
console.log(addtofav("uid-445566",9))
console.log(removeFav("uid-111222",2))
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help but the checkfav function is not checking a specific user favlist, so do u mind if change it a little bit? like i want to check the fav of the specific user that i will give to the function!

Comment: You're welcome it's all fixed now, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you answer your question

Answer (score 0):

1.) Your JSON is malformed. you need to surround everything with {} like this:

```
{
  "servers":
  {
    ...
  },
  "users":
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

So if your favlist is `let favlist = [1, 2, 3]` then you can use `favlist.includes(value)` to see, if your favlist contains an input. Just let your checkExists function return the result of this function.

Since your favlist is an array, you can use `favlist.push(value)` to add values to your array. It does not check for duplicates though.

To remove a specific value from an array, you need to locate the index of that value. Use the following:

```js
/* if value = 2 and favlist = [1,2,3], then this gives index = 1 */
let index = favlist.findIndex(x => x === value); 
favlist.splice(index, 1);
```

Just keep in mind to take care of possible duplicates.